# Stopping a Finite State Machine

Tags: javascript, html, state-machine

I have an application that I have written that adds a set of traffic lights on the screen upon the press of a button. The traffic light automatically cycles from red to yellow after 10 seconds, then on to green after two seconds, then back to yellow after 10 seconds and finally back to red. I have added a control which allows the user to start each traffic light individually. I am trying to figure out how to enable the user to permanently stop each traffic light, without it stopping all the others.

Here is my updated code so far - note the addition of the 'this.stop()' function inside of var Red. I would like the code to stop the rotation there, rather than continue to yellow and green.

Thanks,

Rob

```js
var i = 1;
var TrafficLight = function(i) {
  var count = 0;

  var light_container = document.getElementById('light-container-' + i);
  var currentState = new Red(this, light_container);

  this.change = function(state) {
    currentState = state;
    currentState.go();
  }

  this.start = function() {
    currentState.go();
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    currentState.stop();
  }

}

var Red = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#d8412c';
    console.log(light_container);
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'red', light_container))
    }, 12000);
  }

  this.stop = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    // Switch all the lights off.
    return;
  }
}

var Yellow = function(light, origin, light_container) {
  this.light = light;

  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#fad201';
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (origin == 'red') {
        light.change(new Green(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-red').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      } else if (origin == 'green') {
        light.change(new Red(light, light_container));
        light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-yellow').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
      }
    }, 2000);
  }
}

var Green = function(light, light_container) {
  this.light = light;
  console.log('here');
  this.go = function() {
    light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#33A532';
    setTimeout(function() {
      light.change(new Yellow(light, 'green', light_container))
      light_container.querySelector('.inner-circle-green').style.backgroundColor = '#111111';
    }, 14000);
  }
};


function initiate() {
  var light_container = document.createElement('div');
  light_container.id = "light-container-" + i;
  light_container.className = "light-container";
  light_container.innerHTML = '<div class="outer-circle-red"><div class="inner-circle-red"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-yellow"><div class="inner-circle-yellow"></div></div><div class="outer-circle-green"><div class="inner-circle-green"></div></div><label class="switch"><input type="checkbox" class="off" onclick="toggleRun(this, ' + i + ');"><span class="slider round"></span></label>';
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(light_container);
  i++;
}

function toggleRun(item, i) {
  if (item.className == "off") {
    item.className = "on";
    run(i);
  } else {
    item.className = "off";
    stop(i);
  }
}

function run(i) {

  var light = new TrafficLight(i);

  light.start();

}

function stop(i) {
  var light = new TrafficLight(i);
  light.stop();
}

function exit(status) {

  var i;

  if (typeof status === 'string') {
    alert(status);
  }

  window.addEventListener('error', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  }, false);

  var handlers = [
    'copy', 'cut', 'paste',
    'beforeunload', 'blur', 'change', 'click', 'contextmenu', 'dblclick', 'focus', 'keydown', 'keypress', 'keyup', 'mousedown', 'mousemove', 'mouseout', 'mouseover', 'mouseup', 'resize', 'scroll',
    'DOMNodeInserted', 'DOMNodeRemoved', 'DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument', 'DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', 'DOMAttrModified', 'DOMCharacterDataModified', 'DOMElementNameChanged', 'DOMAttributeNameChanged', 'DOMActivate', 'DOMFocusIn', 'DOMFocusOut', 'online', 'offline', 'textInput',
    'abort', 'close', 'dragdrop', 'load', 'paint', 'reset', 'select', 'submit', 'unload'
  ];



  function stopPropagation(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // e.preventDefault(); // Stop for the form controls, etc., too?
  }
  for (i = 0; i < handlers.length; i++) {
    window.addEventListener(handlers[i], function(e) {
      stopPropagation(e);
    }, true);
  }

  if (window.stop) {
    window.stop();
  }

  throw '';
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button {
  width: 15px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 20px auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.outer-circle-red,
.outer-circle-yellow,
.outer-circle-green {
  background-color: #696969;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  display: table;
}

.light-container {
  margin: 20px 30px 0 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
}

.inner-circle-red,
.inner-circle-yellow,
.inner-circle-green {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  border: 2px solid #111111;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 7.5px;
  background-color: #111111;
}


/* The switch - the box around the slider */

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Hide default HTML checkbox */

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}


/* The slider */

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="button" onclick="initiate()">+ Add a new traffic light</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to save the id returned by `var id = setTimeout()`, so you can use `clearTimeout( id );` later on to completely stop the timeout function from triggering again.

So something like: `this.timeout = setInterval(function(){ /* insert the color changing code */ }, 10000 );`.

If you opt for such a solution, it would be handy to put the timeout code into a single timeout instead of having a separate class for each color. But you can always use an array to store all timeouts and loop over that to cancel if you like having different timeouts for each color.

Comment: Hi @Shilly, sounds like a good suggestion - would you be able to edit my code to illustrate the changes I would need to make to achieve the desired result? That would be very helpful. R

Comment: Just tried, but it requires a full rewrite to actually get them to be able to stop one by one The issue is that traffic light should be a class instead of a state machine like the colors. Then you can use `new TrafficLight()` without the `i` and have actual separate lights instead of all lights sharing state and being forced to use `i` to find out which light to adjust. And that's more work than I have time for today.